# UIcollectionViewCell transition inside of TableViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView that scroll horizontally inside of a tableViewCell. After tapping on collectionView cell, it should move to the center of screen (beyond tableview cell) and then expand something like transition in App store). Is it possible that a cell of cellectionView inside of tableViewCell can have a transition beyond the parent tableview Cell?

I will be apperciate if you can answer me.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no - the tableView cell is constrained to the tableView.   Trying to make it behave otherwise would break the fundamental tableview design.  To get this effect you would need to transition to another view with appropriate animation.

You should also note what it says in Apple's tableView documentation:  *"Do not include scroll views, table views, collection views, or other complex container views in cells.*

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can handle this by re-parenting a subview of the collection view cell.

```swift
let viewToReparent = cell.viewThatIWantToReparent
destinationView.addSubview(viewToReparent)
```

From here you're free to add new auto layout constraints or otherwise manipulate the view's size and position outside of the cell. Maybe you don't actually want to remove the view from the cell, so you could make a copy of it if that suits your use case better. If you want to perform an animated transition to a new screen that contains this view, that's more complicated, and you'll need to look at [custom transitions](https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/view-controller-transitions/).